# Редактирование строки с помощью java regex

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Допустим, у меня есть номер телефона, хранящийся строкой в виде "0991234567".

Какими манипуляциями с регулярными выражениями можно привести эту строку к виду "+450 (99) 123 45 67"?

Comment: А код +45 откуда взялся? Он для всех телефонов одинаковый? Код города всегда (99)? Разбор произвольного телефонного номера - это не совсем тривиальная вещь.

Comment: ну допустим +45 это код страны, а 99 это код оператора. То есть +45 добавляется ко всем номерам. Суть вопроса в том, как используя regex можно вставлять в определенных местах строки нужные символы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если код города и страны постоянно одинаковые (учитывая комментарии) то тут даже не нужны регулярные выражения, комбинация `substring` и `concat` сделает всё.

Если же очень хочется делать это регулярными выражениями, то в простейшем случае я бы написал вот так:

```
string phone = "0991234567";
phone.replaceAll("(\\d)(\\d{2,3})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "+45$1 ($2) $3 $4 $5");
```

Еще раз обращаю внимание, что разбор произвольного номера не делают таким образом. Количество цифр в коде города, страны, количество цифр в самом номере может быть другим.

Comment: Само собой, можно сделать без регулярных выражений, но интересовали именно они, как учебный пример.